# Chern class of line bundle inducing a principal polarisation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

What can one say about the Chern class $c_1(\mathcal{L})$ of a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on an Abelian variety $A$ inducing a (principal) polarisation $A \to A^\vee$?

Why am I asking this? My situation is as follows: Let $A/k$ be an Abelian variety with $k$-endomorphism $f: A \to A$, $\mathcal{L} \in \mathrm{Pic}(A)$ a line bundle inducing a (principal) polarisation $A \to A^\vee$. Now for simplicity let us assume $A$ to be a surface. I want the expression $\mathrm{deg}(((f,c_\mathcal{L})^*\mathcal{P}_A \cup c_1(\mathcal{L})) \in \mathbf{Z}$, where $\mathcal{P}_A$ denotes the Poincaré bundle on $A \times_k A^\vee$ and $c_\mathcal{L}$ the polarisation induced by $\mathcal{L}$, to be independent of the choice of the ample line bundle $\mathcal{L}$.

Edit: In the form stated above, it is wrong: $c_{\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{M}} = c_{\mathcal{L}} + c_{\mathcal{M}}$ and $c_1({\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{M}}) = c_1({\mathcal{L}}) + c_1({\mathcal{M}})$, so if you replace $\mathcal{L}$ by $\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n}$, the term is multiplied by $n^2$.

Perhaps one has to replace $\mathrm{deg}(((f,c_\mathcal{L})^*\mathcal{P}_A \cup c_1(\mathcal{L}))$ by $\mathrm{deg}(((f,c_\mathcal{L})^*\mathcal{P}_A \cup c_1(\mathcal{L})^{-1})$, but this still does not work with all tensor products $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{M}$.

Comment: Dear Timo -- Could you say more precisely what you are looking for?

Comment: I will extend my question in a minute.

Comment: Is it not obvious? It seems to me that the quantity $\mathrm{deg}(((f,c_\mathcal{L})^*\mathcal{P}_A \cup c_1(\mathcal{L})) \in \mathbf{Z}$ only depends on the type of the polarization, i.e. on the *numerical* equivalence class. So it is independent on the actual choice of the line bundle in its numerical class. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Francesco: What if there is more than one principal polarization? For instance, a product of two isomorphic elliptic curves will always have many principal polarizations.

Comment: @Will: you are right, it is not completely obvious

Comment: If $L$ is symmetric and ample then $(f,c_{\cal L})^*{\cal P}_A\simeq L^{\otimes 2}$ so 
${\rm deg}((f,c_{\cal L})^*{\cal P}_A\otimes L^{\otimes -2})$ is independent of the choice of $\cal L$, provided $\cal L$ is symmetric. 

Comment: Well, up to a translation (which does not change the numerical class) one can assume that $\mathcal{L}$ *is* symmetric

Comment: Thank you, Damian. How does one prove your first equation? Why doesn't it depend on $f$?

Comment: @Timo Keller: see for instance Faltings-Chai, "Degeneration of abelian varieties", chap. I, p. 3-4 (esp. middle of p. 4). It doesn't depend on $f$ because, up to $2$-torsion line bundles, two symmetric line bundles, which are algebraically equivalent, must be isomorphic (because the only symmetric line bundle, which is algebraically equivalent to $0$ is a $2$-torsion line bundle).

Comment: "It doesn't depend on $f$" seems to be wrong: Take $f = \mathrm{id}$ and $f = 0$.